# Can I combine spread and rest in destructuring object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Let us have this object:

```js
// Values of properties are irelevant
let row = {_x: "x", _y: "y", _z: "z", a: "a", b: "b"}
```

I need to get copy of this object without properties beginning with underscore (`_`).

I can do this:

```js
const {_x, _y, _z, ...pureRow} = row;
console.log(pureRow); // {a: "a", b: "b"}
```

But I would like to have a list of removed properties in an array and remove all properties listed in this array. Something like:

```js
const auxFields = ["_x", "_y", "_z"];
const {...auxFields, ...pureRow} = row; // Error: A rest element must be last in a destructuring pattern.
console.log(pureRow); // {a: "a", b: "b"}
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there isn't.  But you could create a copy of the whole thing then delete the `auxFields` from it, or e.g. fromEntries to create a new object excluding the properties you don't want.

Comment: You can loop and delete `const copy = { ...row }; auxFields.forEach(k => delete copy[k]);`

Comment: As @epascarello suggested: `const pureRow = { ...row }; auxFields.forEach((k) => delete pureRow[k]);` works exactly as intended. Thanks to you and @jonrsharpe too!